# How do I get the value of the used parameters in a constructor (C#)

Tags: c#, generics, parameters, constructor

I've got a question about getting the values from a constructor in a generic way.

```
namespace myTestNamespace
{
    Public Class myTestClass()
    {
        Public myTestClass(int myInt,bool myBool, double myDouble)
        {
        //do / set something
        }

        Public myTestClass(int myInt,bool myBool)
        {
            //do / set something
        }
    }
}

Using (what you need);
Using myTestNamespace;

namespace MyIWannaLookForTheParametersName
{
    Public Class MyLookUpClass()
    {
        Public void DoSomething()
        {
        List<object> myList = new List<object>();

        myTestClass _ myTestClass = new myTestClass(1,true,2.5);
        object mySaveObject = myTestClass;

        mylist.Add(mySaveObject);

        //how do I get the info from the right constructor 
        //(I used the one with 3 parameters_
        //what was the value of myInt, myBool and myDouble
        //how can I make it generic enough, so it will work with other classes with
        // different constructors ass well?
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do, to be honest. Shouldn't all the information be in the object itself? Why do you care about exactly how it was constructed?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do? (What you have and what you want instead...)

Comment: I like the idea of an ass well

Comment: @C.Evenhuis What do you want to say?

Comment: Hi All, I want to make a back testing system, where different indicators get different parameters settings. They change per loop and I want to store the used settings for all used indicator in a list. Because the indicators use different parameters, it needs to be generic. Regards and thanks for the replies so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what I needed with this method:

```
private static ParameterSettings[] GetListOfParametersFromIndicator(object indicatorClass, int loopId, myEnums.ParaOrResult paraOrResult)
    {
        return (from prop in indicatorClass.GetType().GetProperties()
                 let loopID = loopId
                let Indicator = indicatorClass.GetType().Name
                let value = (object)prop.GetValue(indicatorClass, null)
                 where prop.Name.Contains("_Constr_")
                select new ParameterSettings { ParaOrResult=paraOrResult, LoopID= loopId, Indicator= Indicator, ParaName= prop.Name, Value= value }).ToArray();
    }
```

where ParameterSettings is:

```
public struct ParameterSettings
    {
        public myEnums.ParaOrResult ParaOrResult    { get; set; }
        public int                  LoopID          { get; set; }
        public string               Indicator       { get; set; }
        public string               ParaName        { get; set; }
        public object               Value           { get; set; }
    }
```

This info is ok for me. Thanks for the replies.

Regards,

Matthijs

Comment: Be aware there are potential performance issues with this - The parameters passed in could be huge objects and by keeping a reference to them in memory, you're preventing them from being GC'd. Depending on what you need, performing a `.ToString` might give you 99% of the info for a more manageable memory budget

Answer (score 1):

Questions about intent aside, there's no generic way for you to do this. Information about what methods have been called and what values were supplied is not saved automatically. You are, of course, perfectly able to keep track of these things yourself, but you would have to write each class to do this explicitly.

Doing this in a generic way is asking for trouble. What if I did this?

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public Bar(Foo foo)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then suppose I called it in this way:

```
Foo f = new Foo();

f.Name = "Jim";

Bar b = new Bar(f);

f.Name = "Bob";
```

Now, if such a generic system existed, what would be the value of `foo` for the `Bar` constructor? Either it reports `"Bob"` (which is what the value for `Name` is on the instance of `Foo` that was supplied), or it reports `"Jim"`, meaning that the runtime or library would essentially have to be smart enough to make a deep copy of the object so that the state is not changed.

The bottom line is this: if you need access to the parameters passed to the constructor (or any other function), you'll have to store them somewhere explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get thevalues from the constructor. You need to first place them in a property or a field within your class. The example you provided is a poor use of generics. You wouldbe better off placing the constructor values into properties and creating an interface with those properties.